What is a good surface for a large outdoor playground slide?
I'm making plans to build an outdoor playground slide.  I don't like the cost, size, or shape of most commercial plastic slides.  I'd like to make it 4 feet wide with a divider in the middle, and rails on the sides.  I have the main deck figured out, but that's the easy part.
One major hurdle is deciding what the sliding surface should be.  I've seen people online using rolls aluminum flashing, but I have a friend who tried that and he said the aluminum isn't hard enough and gets scratched easily, so it eventually stops being slippery.
I'm thinking a good option would be using plywood with 2x4s underneath for strength.  Then I would coat the plywood.
What would make a good coating for the plywood?  What would last outdoors and remain slippery?  Epoxy?  Polyurethane?  Are there other options?

fiberglass would be an option

Talk to your insurance provider before starting. That's (likely) most of the cost of expensive commercial units, and if you build your own, it's your own liability at stake.

To whoever closed my question, I don't see how it's at all similar to the type of product recommendation in the linked article: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/
I'm asking about types of materials, not about specific products from specific companies.  I don't see how a recommendation for epoxy, polyethylene, etc. would become obsolete quickly.

I just checked McMaster-Carr and Grainger and both carry UHMWPE, aka Ultra-High-Molecular-Weight-PolyEthylene plastic in sheet form. I didn't dig deeper into the width or thickness options, leaving that as an exercise to the reader.
UHMWPE is a big brother to the skinny (and slippery) single use grocery bags reviled by many. I've purchased the product in 10mm to 75mm thicknesses and the above vendors list fractional thicknesses as well.
It's astonishingly durable, and is used as grease-free spacers on the fifth wheels of semi-trailers. It's also very slippery, even when scratched. It can be challenging to locate suitable adhesive, but for your application, mechanical fasteners may be a better choice.
There's a UV durable version that's light grey. The non-UV version can be expected to deteriorate in sunlight after about a decade, based on my use, but that wasn't full time daylight. I'm sure everyone who enjoyed the gravity of a playground slide knows how hot one of these things can get. The plastic might not be as bad.
